# extract string from a file in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have a .kla file that has 2 strings (Name,ID) and I need to extract their valuables and combine them to make a new name for a new file (Name_ID.kla) to be saved.

```
Name "Jon";
ID 1234;
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edited** to adapt to changes in question

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "name="
    set "id="

    for /f "usebackq tokens=1,*" %%a in (
        "input.kla"
    ) do for %%c in (%%b) do set "%%a=%%~c"

    if defined name if defined id (
        type nul >"%name%_%id%.kla"
    )
```

Read the input file and, using the spaces as delimiters (default behaviour in `for /f`), use the first field as key and the second as value (once the second `for` removes `"` and `;`) to define environment variables. If the required variables get defined, generate the new file.

Comment: My dear i m really thankful for your kindness. if i want to get ID 1234 (i mean without quotes) how can i do that? thanks again.